# Let $K$ be a field and $P,Q \in K[X]$. Let $a \in K \setminus\{0\}$. Show that if $Q$ divides $P$, then $aQ$ divides $P$ also.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $K$ be a field and $P,Q \in K[X]$. Let $a \in K \setminus\{0\}$. Show that if $Q$ divides $P$, then $aQ$ divides $P$ also.

Since $K$ is a field and $a$ is non-zero there exists $b \in K$ such that $ab=1$. That is $a$ is a unit.

Now as $Q$ divides $P$ we have that $$P=QS, S \in K[X].$$

Since $K$ is a field do I automatically get that $a$ divides $P$? If so then this is equivalent to showing that if $a \mid P$ and $Q \mid P$, then $aQ \mid P$. But this only holds when $\gcd(a, Q)=1$?

Comment: You're overthinking: $P = QS = (ab)QS = (aQ)(bS)$

Answer (score 1):

Well, in a commutative ring $R$, one can say that divisibility is unique modulo units.

If $a\mid b$ and $u$ is a unit in $R$, then $ua\mid b$.

Indeed, since $ac=b$ for some $c\in R$ and $uv=1$ for some unit $v$.
Then $b=1b=uvb=uvac = (ua)(vc)$ and so $ua\mid b$.